# Axis drawn longer than specified

Tags: pgfplots

The y-axis in the following graph is about ten times higher than I want it to be.  The graph has a maximum height of 0.5 units.  I specify that the y-axis should go up to 2 units.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes,decorations.markings}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=6in,axis equal image,clip=false,
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-2,xmax=2,
    domain=-2:2, samples=201,
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$V$,
    ymin=-1,ymax=2,
    restrict y to domain=-2:2,
    enlargelimits={abs=0.5cm},
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    ticklabel style={font=\tiny,fill=white},
    xtick={1},ytick={0.5},
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south west}
]
\addplot[samples=501,domain=0:1.73205,blue] {0.25 *(3*x - x^(3))} node[right, pos=0.75,font=\footnotesize]{$y = \frac{3x - x^{3}}{4}$};
\addplot[samples=501,domain=-2:0,blue, dashed] {0.25 *(3*x - x^(3))};
\addplot[samples=501,domain=1.73205:2,blue, dashed] {0.25 *(3*x - x^(3))};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Remove `enlargelimits={abs=0.5cm}` that is extra 5mm converted to axis units. And extra space comes from `ymax=2` which is high compared to the function values. Enable y ticks to see it.

Answer (score 3):

Although you are not printing the maximum is at `y=2` and then 0.5cm is added on top of it. Hence your plot is already big and 5 milimeters more is not making it as big as it is seen.

As an example, I've just modified `ymax=1` and commented `,ytick={0.5},` part. The result is

[image]